# Función replace predefinida python

Tags: python, python-3.x

me podrían pasar una función que cumpla el mismo objetivo que el replace() en python? dado que no nos dejan usar funciones definidas

Diseñar un procedimiento que elimine los espacios blancos sobrantes
de una cadena de caracteres dada. Se considera espacio sobrante
cuando:
Existen espacios blancos al comenzar la cadena. En este caso
deben ser eliminados.
Existen dentro de la cadena más de un espacio en blanco
seguido. En este caso debe dejarse sólo un.
Existen espacios en blanco al final de la cadena. En este caso
deben ser eliminados

```
def replace(Espaciooriginal,Espaciosobrado,Cadena):
            for i in range(len(Cadena)+1):
                    letra = Cadena[i-1:i]
                    if letra==Espaciooriginal:
                        NuevaCadena = NuevaCadena+Espaciosobrado
                    else:
                        NuevaCadena = NuevaCadena+Cadena[i-1:i]
            return NuevaCadena              
        
        Cadena = str(input("Ingrese una cadena: "))
        Espaciooriginal = " "
        Espaciosobrado = "  "
        
        
        for i in range(len(Cadena)):
            Cadena = replace(Espaciooriginal,Espaciosobrado, Cadena)
            
            
        if Cadena[0] == " ":
                
            Cadena = Cadena[1:(len(Cadena)+1)]
            
        if Cadena[(int(len(Cadena)-1))] == " ":
                
                Cadena = Cadena[:(len(Cadena)-1)]
        
        
        print("La nueva cadena es: " + str(Cadena)) #Salida
```

Comment: Aqui no hacemos código a pedido. Ayudamos con problemas de programación. Además, si se trata de una tarea, probablemente el punto sea que vos mismo crees esa funcion.

Comment: El codigo es ese pero no funciona con el replace diseñado para eliminar espacios sobrantes, por?

Comment: Este código esta totalmente mal indentado. Por favor corrige la indentación si quieres que alguien te ayude correctamente. Te iba a ayudar pero no entiendo tu código